# Magento incl. and excl. TAX not showing correctly for GUESTS

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat

I have configured magento 1.9.x CE to display catalog prices including and excluding VAT (TAX) at 20% which is working fine for logged in users under the "General" customer group. Both Incl and Excl TAX prices are calculated correctly for these logged in users.

However for guest users no TAX is being calculated, both prices incl and excl TAX are showing identical values.

[image: incl and excl tax are showing incorrect with no tax calculated for guest customers]

All settings are configured correctly and the "NONE Logged in users" (guests) are set to use the same tax configuration as "logged in" (normal) customers.

[image: VAT (TAX) configuration]

Any thoughts on why VAT (TAX) is not being calculated for "Not logged in" (Guest) customers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a hidden origin shipping setting under one of the configuration scopes. Once i set this to "United Kingdom" the website started showing the VAT correctly. Prior to this it was defaulting to "None" which was causing guests to appear with no Country assigned hence no TAX could be calculated.

So if anyone else is unlucky enough to come across this issue check all your settings, even configuration scopes you dont usually look in.